# Rendered pork fat vs lard vs bacon fat?

Tags: pork, fat, bacon

What is the difference between "rendered pork fat", lard, and bacon fat?

I've seen lots of references to rendered pork fat in the [Momofuku cookbook](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00480OV08), references to lard in one of my Schezuan [cookbooks](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0393051773), and well everyone knows bacon fat...   so what is the difference ?  Can you substitute them ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not a lot, bacon is basically brined and smoked pork (the process/recipe depends on where you live)

Fat does not actually change in flavour as much as the flesh does when smoked

"Rendered fat" is just the fat that has run off when heating meat. It should be pure fat, with all the impurity left behind, or skimmed off

Depending on where you live, lard is either just pork fat, or a common word for animal fat

In Asian cooking if it specifies pork fat I would use that. Most Schezuan recipes are not smokey flavour based, so it may be noticeable, and appear unusual

Comment: Bacon pork cured by salting not smoke. It may or may not be smoked as well as salted. The salting will change the taste of the fat as moisture will be drawn out.

Comment: @Rincewind42 Salting and smoking meat effects the flesh (protein) of the meat, not the fat. Salt does not significantly change fat any more that adding some salt to the final dish would. Rendered fat should not have any moisture in it

Comment: Incorrect. Salting, as done for bacon or ham, requires leaving the meat in the salt for several days or even weeks. The salt causes an osmosis effect that draws water out of the cells, drying the meat. This has simlar effect on all cells, wither fat cells or meat cells.

Comment: Animal fat is 90%+ triglycerides, some other bits, and a few % water. When rendered the water is released. So as per OP this is equivalent

Comment: Dumb question - if lard and rendered pork fat are the same, how come the lard I bought is bone white and the rendered pork fat I saved (from cooking pork belly) is brownish?

Comment: @Marcus As stated in answer; Lard and rendered pork fat are not the same. Pork lard and rendered pork fat are the same. Most common lards are beef or mutton fat. Pork fat saved from cooking pork belly is not the same as rendering fat, which removes all impurities

Comment: @Marcus It is because the fat you saved from cooking probably has little bits of cooked meat in it. This is especially true if you fried it in a skillet. When I make bacon, I slow cook it in the oven on a wire rack placed in a baking dish. The fat collects in the baking dish, and once poured int a jar and cooled, it is also pure white.

Comment: I know I'm a bit late here, but that's an interesting definition of lard you're using. In the real world that the rest of us live in, "lard" is [defined](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/lard) as rendered **pork** fat. Rendered beef or mutton fat is called *tallow*, not lard.

Comment: Yes, rendered beef fat is called tallow.  I have not heard a name for rendered sheep fat, but perhaps one exists.

Answer (score 0):

Bacon fat, rendered fat, lard or pork fat differ in purity but not basic chemical structure. Mutton and beef tallow is called suet. Back fats.